# Safari shows bigger font-size in landscape mode

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design

In my current responsive project I have the issue that when using my iPhone in landscape mode, the font-size is a lot bigger and introducing `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` didn't help (see JSFiddle below).

I use these definitions in my project:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

and the breakpoints

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 35em) and (orientation:portrait) {
  ...
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 47em) and (orientation:landscape) {
  body {
     -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 35em) and (orientation:portrait),
       only screen and (max-width: 47em) and (orientation:landscape) {
...
}
```

You can directly test it at the [**result page**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzstg7ck/6/embedded/result/) of my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzstg7ck/6/).

```
<div class="test">This is just a test</div>
<div class="test">This is just a test</div>
<div class="test">This is just a test</div>
<div class="test">This is just a test</div>
<div class="test">This is just a test</div>
```

and

```
@viewport {
  width: device-width;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 47em) and (orientation:landscape) {
  body {
     -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
}

.test {
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    height:2em;
    font-size:3em;
}
.test:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
```

What can be wrong?

**UPDATE**:

- Even without breakpoints it doesn't work, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzstg7ck/14/)

**UPDATE 2015-07-15**

- I found a workaround: Disable the zoom for mobile phones would solve the problem. However, as tablets get the desktop version, zoom must be enabled for tablets. I achieved a working solution now by checking the screen size in javascript and if it is below 752px I modify the viewport definition to `width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0`

Comment: why did u use `max-width` with `em` which is relative unit? I recommend changing it to `px` and see if problem solved

Comment: Is this happening with px as well as em untis?

Comment: @Trix I used `em` because that seems the way to go, there are hundreds of discussions out there about whether to use `em` or `px`... I will test it but this can't be the root cause...

Comment: @all : em or px does not matter, it even doesn't work without any breakpoint, see http://jsfiddle.net/Lzstg7ck/14/

Comment: Do you want to allow users to pinch to zoom etc?

Comment: @Alan unfortunately yes, because on the iPad the Desktop-Version is shown and there you must be able to zoom... I tried to define a view port definition within the media query, but that didn't work (obviously it is not yet supported). If zooming would be disallowed, there wouldn't be any problem, I know... I don't see any solution at this moment...

Comment: Yes, everyhting you said makes sense. Disabling zooming would likely solve your prob. Have you tried giving an font-size for different viewports? For example, fon-tsize for ipad, iphone etc?

Comment: I think you can't solve it via font-size, because Android devices do not zoom in for landscape mode, so the result would be a smaller font in landscape mode on Android phones, also not what I really want. However I found a workaround, I'll update my question.